# Pack bubble chart depending on the size of circle

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, size, pack

I would like to pack correctly my bubble chart project (I change the size thanks to a value in my JSON `.attr("r", function(d) { return d.size; }))`, if I have a lot of bubble, they overlap. I check the .pack() method on the dock but I don't correctly use it, I don't understand how to use it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

    var diameter = 960,
            format = d3.format(",d"),
            color = d3.scale.category20c();

    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
            .sort(null)
            .size([diameter, diameter])
            .padding(1.5);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", diameter)
            .attr("height", diameter)
            .attr("class", "bubble");


    d3.json("./data.json", function(error, root) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
                 .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

        node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

        node.append("circle")
                .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size; })
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.size); });

        node.append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".3em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });

    });

    // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
    function classes(root) {
        var classes = [];
        function recurse(name, node) {
            if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
           else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size, size: node.size});
        }
        recurse(null, root);
        return {children: classes};
    }
    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

</script>
</body>
```

This is the project Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/PjN6v3dr2yP3oST5sCTB?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line :

```
.attr("r", function(d) {return d.size; })
```

Use `d.r` which is generated by the bubble pack :

```
.attr("r", function(d) {return d.r; })
```

Updated plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/ao9RbxOKQ7VuobzOsVJd?p=preview

Comment: The bubble pack knows the size as you pass it to the value in the recurse function : value:node.size

Comment: Ok, thanks it works ! `.attr("r", function(d) {return d.r; })` was in the orginal example, so I don't understand what is the attribute : `.value(function(d) { console.log(d.size);return d.size; })`